# Визуализация данных seaborn / pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Не могу понять вот что. У меня есть таблица `DataFrame` следующего вида:

```
 id    Игрок 1     Игрок 2    Рейтинг (Игрок 1)   Рейтинг (Игрок 2)
  1     Миша        Саша            20               15
  2     Артем       Данил           120              8
```

Мне нужно построить столбчатую диаграмму, по оси y рейтинг, по x id 1: 2 столбца разных цветов  (рейтинг игрока 1 и рейтинг игрока 2), id 2 и тд

Функция нужная мне: `sns.barplot(x="", y="", hue="", data=df);`

Вопрос: как нужно правильно вставить данные в оси, чтобы получить нужный результат? Возможно необходимо как-то преобразовать таблицу, но я никак не допру как.

Answer (score 2):

Можно преобразовать таблицу так:

```
df1 = initial_df[['id', 'Рейтинг (Игрок 1)']].rename(columns = {'Рейтинг (Игрок 1)':'Рейтинг'})
df1['Номер игрока'] = 1
df2 = initial_df[['id', 'Рейтинг (Игрок 2)']].rename(columns = {'Рейтинг (Игрок 2)':'Рейтинг'})
df2['Номер игрока'] = 2
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(df)

id  Рейтинг  Номер игрока
1       20             1
2      120             1
1       18             2
2        5             2
```

Затем построить график:

```
sns.barplot(data = df, x = 'id', y = 'Рейтинг', hue = 'Номер игрока')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]